# Paying off an installment

Tags: numerics, recursion, difference-equations, finance, infinite-loop

How do I determine the weekly installment I have to pay, if my loan is, let's say, `loan=5000`, with interest rate of `2%` every week, and I have to settle it in 52 weeks. This is my code so far.

```
amt = 5000;
interestrate = 2;
nlast = 52;
inst = (* I do not know how to obtain this *);

Do[
  interest = amt*interestrate;
  amt = (amt + (interest/100.0)) - inst;
  Print["this is the ", n, " week."];
  Print[" I pay the installment ", inst, " per week, the remaining amount I have to pay is ", amt];
  Print[" "];
  If[amt < 0, inst = inst + 1],
 {n, 1, nlast, 1}
];
```

Comment: I like, how the tag on a thread about paying off debt is "infinite-loop" :)

Comment: FWIW you do not have an infinite loop.  With `inst` unspecified `amt` is a symbolic expression that grows larger and larger with each iteration. (And you are trying to print this big thing to the screen every time).  Try runninfg with `nlast=10` and you'll see..

Comment: An "interest rate of `2%` every week" could mean an annual effective interest rate of 180% p.a. depending on interpretation.  `(1 + 0.02)^52 - 1 = 1.8003`.  Do you mean an annual effective rate of 2%, or a nominal rate of 2% compounded weekly? (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation))

Comment: yes, effective interest rate is 180% like u said. 2% weekly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to show how to fix the origional loop:

```
amt = 5000;
interestrate = .02;
nlast = 52;
Do[interest = amt*interestrate;
  amt = Simplify[amt + interest - inst], {n, 1, nlast, 1}];
Solve[amt == 0, inst]
```

> inst -> 155.545

Note the `Simplify` is important here, without it `amt` looks like this after just 4 weeks..

> ```
>      5100. + 0.02 (5100. + 0.02 (5100. + 0.02 (5100. - inst) - 2 inst) + 
> 0.02 (5100. - inst) - 3 inst) +  0.02 (5100. + 0.02 (5100. - inst) - 2 inst) + 0.02 (5100. - inst) -  4 inst
> ```

It is correct but will be horribly slow even if you don't try to print it.

Answer (score 15):

Using `Annuity`:

```
pmt /.Solve[TimeValue[Annuity[pmt, 52, 1], .02, 0] == 5000, pmt]
```

> `155.545`

Exercise left for the reader...

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

The general formula can be derived as follows.

```
First@RSolve[{prin[n] == (1 + int) prin[n - 1] - pay, prin[0] == loan}, prin[n], n];
First@Solve[(prin[n] /. %) == 0, pay]
(* {pay -> (int (1 + int)^n loan)/(-1 + (1 + int)^n)} *)
```

where `pay` is the payment per period,  `int` is the interest per period, and `loan` is the original principal.

For the example given in the question,

```
pay /. % /. {n -> 52, loan -> 5000, int -> .02}
(* 155.545 *)
```

and the total amount needed to pay off the loan is `8088.36`.

Answer (score 5):

Using the example for an ordinary annuity from here:-

[Calculating The Present And Future Value Of Annuities](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/03/101503.asp)

The example demonstrates how a present value principal of 4329.48 is paid down by five repayments of 1000 each discounted to present value by the interest rate and period.

[image]

The calculation can be represented by the following summation:

[image]

where `p`is the principal, `d` is the periodic payment, `r` is the periodic interest rate and `n` is the number of periods.

By [induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039786/induction-of-closed-form-of-summation) this can be converted to a [standard formula](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html).

Mathematica does the induction calculation automatically:

[image]

```
p = (d - d (1 + r)^-n)/r

∴ d = (p r)/(1 - (1 + r)^-n)
```

Substituting your figures with variations, since 2% is rather high for a weekly rate and more typical of an annual rate.

```
principal, p = 5000
number of periods, n = 52

for annual effective rate of interest = 2%
weekly rate, r = (1 + 0.02)^(1/52) - 1 = 0.000380892

d = (p r)/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 97.1275
```

So with a 2% [annual effective rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) of interest the weekly instalment is 97.13

```
for an annual nominal rate of 2% compounded weekly
weekly rate, r = 0.02/52 = 0.000384615

d = (p r)/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 97.1371
```

With a 2% [nominal rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) compounded weekly the weekly instalment is 97.14

Alternatively, with periodic (weekly) rate, `r = 2% = 0.02`

```
d = (p r)/(1 - (1 + r)^-n) = 155.545
```

With a weekly rate of 2% the annual effective rate is `(1 + 0.02)^52 - 1 = 180% per annum` and the weekly instalment is 155.55